# How can I store raw stringified JSON in a sqlite column?

Tags: python, json, sqlite

I'm using sqlite3 with python, and I'm trying to do a easy way of storing raw JSON into a certain column called "data." Every time I try to concatenate the stringified JSON into the INSERT statement I get a syntax error. Is there any way of fixing this?

```
data = str({'test': 21, 'test2':'hello'})
query = f"INSERT INTO table (DATA) VALUES ('{data}')"
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, instead of concatinating the string before doing c.execute you can just do c.execute("INSERT INTO table (c1, c2, c3) VALUES (?,?,?)", [c1, c2, c3])

Answer (score 0):

What's the type of the column in your database? I would suggest to store your JSON as string/varchar type into the database. You could also convert it to a blob, but I think strings are easier to handle.

Comment: I am attempting to store it as a string; however, the whenever input it like so and run the query, I get a syntax error from SQLITE

Answer (score 0):

can't you stringify, store and parse

```
db.run("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table (data TEXT)");

stmt = db.prepare("INSERT INTO table VALUES (?)");
stmt.run(JSON.stringify(data));
stmt.finalize();


  db.each("SELECT rowid AS id, info FROM table", (err, row) => {
      console.log(row.id + ": " + JSON.parse(row.data).test);
  });
```